# React: Updating state in parent component from multiple child components

Tags: reactjs

Am new to react and i encountered a problem while trying this out. I have a 2d array in the parent state which i mapped into several child's components. I have a check box in the parent component which when clicked should get the values in the all the child's components and update the 2d array. I created a function to do this in  the parent component and send as prop to all the child's components but the change is not reflected in the 2d array present in the parent component. Only the first element in the array is updated. Help me out please. The function passed to the child component is

```
    updateStudentScores = (
    index,
    test1,
    test2,
    exams,
    totals,
    grades,
    remks,
    SChek,
    bgrnd
  ) => {
    const elementsIndex = this.state.students.findIndex(
      (element) => element.RealIndex == index
    );

    let newArray = [...this.state.tempStudents];
    newArray[elementsIndex] = {
      ...newArray[elementsIndex],
      Cas1: test1,
      Cas2: test2,
      Exam: exams,
      Total: totals,
      Grade: grades,
      Remark: remks,
      stillChecked: SChek,
      background: bgrnd,
    };
    this.setState({ tempStudents: newArray });
  };
```

tempStudents is the 2d array in the parent component state. Thanks for your response

Comment: You should update your question with your codes for clarity

Answer (score 0):

***The reason it only updates the first element is because when the first child component updates the 2D array it updates the parents state -> which sends it as an updated prop to all children -> causing them all to re-render and lose any inputted data.***

You haven't posted any code... but the best way to do this is to have a handler called every time a child changes anything in the 2D array. (this is ideal)

To get your intended functionality you will need the checkbox to change a state that is passed as a prop to all the child components (causing them to re-render) and when that happens you can use a hook or a lifecycle method like "componentDidMount()" to call the handler of the parent with all the values needed to update the array.

Comment: I have included my callback function. Please help out

Comment: I think the callback function is executed simultaneously by each child component each having different state of tempStudent array to work on. Is there a way i can make sure that one callback finishes executing before the next by child's components so that they will always have the correct tempStudent to work with

Comment: That isn't how react works. And they are not executing simultaneously. The children call the callback function in the order they are rendered.

As i mentioned once a child updates the parents state via a callback it will re-render all the child components (and erase any data they might have in them).

Comment: Ok here is how you may go about this. Instead of updating `tempStudents` create a new state called `tempStudents2` that is updated via the callback function.

You probably have a handler for the checkbox right? Well once the checkbox is checked the children will call the callback function but because they update `tempStudent2` it won't cause other children to re-render. At the end of the checkbox handler do `this.setState({tempStudents: this.state.tempStudents2})`

Comment: Thanks again. I have done what you said but i discovered that each child's call back is reading the initial value of tempStudents2. For instance if child1 updates tepmStudents2 from [1,2,3,4] to [5,6,7,8], instead of child2 to read tempStudent2 as [5,6,7,8], it will still be read as [1,2,3,4] therefore invalidating the changes made by child1 and so on, even the tenth child reads tempStudents2 as [1,2,3,4]

Comment: I guess d reason is because of asynchronous way the setstate works

Comment: I tried to add a settimeout function in the callback function to allow some time for the setstate to update before the next callback function is executed by the next child. Thou it works but am not convinced it's the best way to do this. Please if you have any other way, kindly put me through

Comment: @Applause haha I assumed the intention functionality for each child was what you wanted. Sorry! Don't be afraid to post more code next time. 

Unfortunately, I've worked in react for a while now and have no clue how you can get your current implementation to work. Either a child causes a re-render of other children (tempStudents) or doesn't (tempStudents2) and in both cases, it doesn't give you the desired result.

Comment: @Applause Timeouts are bad practice but I don't have another solution for you at the moment. Best of luck

Comment: Ok. Thanks so much for your responses. I really appreciate